# Same simple calculation, different results

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point, gcc4.8

Using gcc 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 14.04) I get different results while basically calculating a value the same way. There's also a difference depending on the architecture (32 Bit / 64 Bit) on the systems I tested.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float h = 0.11f; 
    float y = 0.11f;
    float g = 1.37906f;
    float x = 2.916949f;

    float result1 = (h * y / fabs(g)) / x;

    float result2 = h * y / fabs(g);
    result2 /= x;

    float result3 = (h * y / g) / x;

    printf("%.20f \n", result1); //0.00300796888768672943 
    printf("%.20f \n", result2); //0.00300796912051737309 
    printf("%.20f \n", result3); //0.00300796912051737309 on x64
                                 //0.00300796888768672943 on x32 
}
```

What's the reason for this and how can I anticipate or avoid these differences ?

Edit: Casting the fabs to float doesn't change the results, at least on my system (see comments by Oli Charlesworth).

Comment: Asking for 20 digits of output from a single-precision (23-bit) float is mostly meaningless.

Comment: Yes,it is menaingless for precision, but it shows the differences. Note that to exactly represent the value of the bits of a float you may need more than 20 digits.

Comment: @Leushenko Any finite single-precision floating-point number represents some number exactly, and there are plenty of reasons to want to see an exact decimal representation of this number (which often implies printing many more than 20 decimal digits).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of forcing all C compilers to implement an exacting standard for floating-point computation like early Java standards did, the C99 standard allows some variation with respect to an ideal mode where each operation is done in order and rounded according to the IEEE 754 format corresponding to the floating-point type.

You can ask GCC what floating-point computation model it is following, and you can use commandline options to change its behavior and make it more predictable.
There are two cases:

1. If you are going to generate 387 code, compile with a recent GCC (4.8 should be fine) and `-std=c99`. Without it (specifically, without `-fexcess-precision=standard` that it implies), the exact result of floating-point computation is unpredictable, and you are allowing the compiler to produce different results for `result1`, `result2` and `result3`). With `-std=c99`, the values of `result1` and `result3` must be identical. The value of `result2` can be different because the intermediate assignment to `result2` forces the value at that point of the computation to be rounded to a `float`.
2. Stop generating 387 code, generate SSE2 code instead (options `-msse2 -mfpmath=sse`). In this mode, all three computations in which `fabs` has been replaced by `fabsf` should produce the same result. This has the drawback of generating code that is only compatible with processors produced in the last 12 years or so(!)

More information: [post1](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/07/06/On-the-precise-analysis-of-C-programs-for-FLT_EVAL_METHOD-2), [post2](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/07/24/More-on-FLT_EVAL_METHOD_2), written from the point of view of someone who intends to write a static analyzer for C programs that precisely predicts the results of floating-point computations.

Answer (score 2):

The first two differ because `fabs` returns a `double`.  Thus in the first version, the division by `x` is done in double-precision.  In the second version, it's done in single-precision.

Comment: Thanks, that explains the first difference. Interestingly, when executing the first method using my GPU (CUDA), I get the result of the second method.

Comment: Hmm, I tested your solution. I get the same results when casting the results of all the fabs to float.

Comment: @JerrodWilson: This may also be platform-dependent (due to intermediate results being maintained in wider registers); see e.g. http://ideone.com/PjlRXC.

Comment: @Jerrod: the cast is just saying you know what you're doing..  you need to call the specific float function fabsf.

Comment: @Rob11311: That's true. It also doesn't change the results though.

Answer (score -1):

The reason is that you use `float` type which has a precision of about 6 decimal digits.
And results agree within first 6 significant digits.

Comment: No. `x + y` and `y + x` where `x` and `y` are floats are not simply required to match to 6 decimal digits, they are required to be identical. Similarly, all three computations (once `fabs` is replaced with `fabsf`) are identical in some computation models and must produce the same results in these models. Your “6 decimal digits” explanation is just renouncement to understand. Furthermore, the mechanisms that cause differences in the 7th decimal digit can cause differences in the third, second, or first decimal digit for other computations, so they should be understood by a C programmer.

Comment: Sorry, I've never heard the results must be identical. And the calculations are not identical. As Oli Charlesworth says, `fabs` returns `double`, so it forces promotion of all floats to doubles in calculating `result1`. However in `result2` calculation an intermediate result is stored, thus truncated to float, and final division is done in floats. So it is obviously NOT identical to `result1`. And `result3` can be calculated in floats only - so it is also NOT identical to others. Do a compilation to assembly language and compare the code for all three calculations.

Comment: The question says to add casts to `float` for the results of `fabs`. Once this modification is made, all three results are identical for a compiler that rightfully defines FLT_EVAL_METHOD to 0. The values of result1 and result3 are guaranteed to be identical for a compiler that rightfully defines FLT_EVAL_METHOD to 1 or 2.